# Wordpress form is not submitting

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, action

Hello I am very new to WordPress on my requirement I have created a couple of php files in wordpress theme. Where detailsform.php consists

```
<form method="post" name="details" action="customerdetails.php">
```

where after clicking submit button the form has to redirect to customerdetails.php in php it is working fine but in wordpress it is giving 404 error(page not found) I kept all new php files in the existing theme folder.

Please suggest me it is killing my time.

Comment: your file path is correct?

Comment: I placed php files in my theme folder it is at htdocs/wp-content/themes/my-theme

Comment: what is your current file path?

Comment: does both the file exists in same directory?? According to current direction, both should be in same path.

Comment: yes my files are in the same directory

Answer (score 5):

As wordpress has its very own specific way to handle ajax calls, wordpress has it too for post http request by form submitting. In the [codex on wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)) there is more details about that.

In a brief explanation, using your functions.php file on your wordpress theme:

The first thing you need to do is set in your action attribute from your *form* tag, point the following url:

`<form action="http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_handler_function">
 </form>`

Once pointed, you need to add a *hidden input* with the name attribute *action* and a value attribute specifying the name of your action. Then, you need to build your handler function on your functions.php file. This is where your going to write the code you need for treat the data you will received by the global **$_POST** or **$_REQUEST** variable.

```
function my_handler_function() {
  var_dump($_REQUEST);
  die();
//request handlers should die() when they complete their task
}
```

Next step is to bound this function to your form by using the action hook  *admin_post_nopriv_* or *admin_post_*. The difference between these, is where your form is placed. If your form is for a custom functionality for the admin of wordpress then is private and you use *admin_post* hook action. If this form is part of your public content then use the *admin_post_nopriv_* like in the following example:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_my_handler_function', 'my_handler_function' );
```

As it is show in the code example above, you need to call the [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/#description) function. In the first parameter, It is needed to pass the action hook provide by wordpress combined with the action value specify in the *hidden input* named *action* in the form, like *admin_post_nopriv_$action_value*. In the second parameter, you need to placed the function name you build on you functions.php file. Both are mandatory.

For matters of conventions, generally, the name of the function handler is set it as same as the value of the action input to avoid misunderstandings and gain more readability.

Onced everything is put it all together, all you have to do is test your code.

Happy coding!!

PD: If you want to clarify about this procedure of wordpress, please take a look in the **wp-admin/admin-post.php** file, but don't even dare to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Put your file customerdetails.php in current theme and use following path in action:-

  <form method="post" name="details" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/customerdetails.php">
```

Answer (score 2):

1. edit your php file with template.
   Ex. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Customer Details Page
*/
get_header();
?>
// your php file as it is.
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

2. now create new page with "customerdetails" name in wp admin & select "Customer Details Page" in right side column & save.
3. now your form action path will be as below

```html
<form method="post" name="details" action="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/customerdetails">
```

Now your form is getting submitted & customerdetails page also receive post data.

Answer (score 1):

404 error means the action is wrong for form.

```
<form method="post" name="details" action="customerdetails.php">
                                          ^                   ^
```

Correct the action to exact path of `customerdetails.php`

Comment: I tried with path c:\\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\my-theme\customerdetails.php

Answer (score 1):

Issue must be with path (form redirection URL on submission), try with full url.
Can you share the URL at which you have put your form ??

Comment: thats wrong, its an absoulte path , it wont work. Use path with domain(server) like http://localhost/wp-content/themes/my-theme/customerdetails.php